# Filter for realtime questions

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, realtime-questions

Is there something I can do that will filter [realtime Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) questions so I only see questions in real time from sites I choose?

A huge bonus would even be a preview of the question text along with the title and such.

Or should I attempt to write some program to monitor the page and push questions from there to somewhere else?

Comment: You can write any program you want, you can try and if bumping into problems... ask on Stack Overflow. Note you should use the API though: https://api.stackexchange.com/ (not screenscrape the page.)